# How would I go about creating my own implementation of IUserAuthRepository?

Tags: servicestack, authentication

I was working with out of the box authentication, with service stack, and it works great. So, right now, I am mocking up a user with the following lines of code, taken from ServiceStack examples:

```
            var userRep = new InMemoryAuthRepository();
            container.Register<IUserAuthRepository>(userRep);
            string hash;
            string salt;
            new SaltedHash().GetHashAndSaltString("test", out hash, out salt);
            userRep.CreateUserAuth(new UserAuth
            {
                Id = 1,
                DisplayName = "DisplayName",
                Email = "as@if.com",
                UserName = "john",
                FirstName = "FirstName",
                LastName = "LastName",
                PasswordHash = hash,
                Salt = salt,
            }, "test");
```

Is there someway I can define the fields in userRep? For example, lets say I want to have the field portalid as well as part of the UserAuth object? How would I go about doing this? Can I just modify the InMemoryAuthRepository class?

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the Schema of [ServiceStack's built-in UserAuth](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Authentication-and-authorization) DTOs, but it does provide a few extensibility points which are [explained in detail in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11118747/85785) where you could use the `RefId` and `RefIdStr` fields to reference your own custom tables or add metadata in the UserAuth row by adding metadata to the `Dictionary<string,string> Meta` collection.

Comment: I looked at that example, but I don't think I fully understood. It's probably because of my infantile understanding, but how does creating a customer user session with the parameters of my choice help me?

Comment: Help you do what exactly? I've only mentioned that you can't change the built-in UserAuth schema, you can only extend it with the hooks described above.