# Is it possible to extend ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.Auth?

Tags: c#, servicestack

Is it possible to extend ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.Auth? to add more properties than username and password? I have created a custom AuthProvider and want to accept 3 parameters in the auth request. Currently there is only Username and Password. I want to extend that to accept a 3rd parameter in the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to extend the Typed Auth Schema itself, although there are a few different strategies you can use that lets you [attach additional metadata to the UserAuth tables in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11118747/85785).