# Linking credential-based authentication information with OAuth

Tags: c#, authentication, oauth, servicestack

I am implementing a proof-of-concept site that can be optionally linked with an external provider. 
The external provider will be used to get some additional user data. The provider conveniently exposes authentication with OAuth 1.0a.

To get the data, the user authenticates on the provider site and grant permission. Easy.

The site uses ServiceStack. Users register and login using a `CredentialsAuthProvider`. I have looked at the docs on ServiceStack, explored the SocialBoostrapApi demo, and modeled my services accordingly;

First, I added a `User` class, that will be serialized to my DB, to hold the additional data.

Then, I created a CustomUserSession, to override the `OnAuthenticated` method.

```
Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new CustomUserSession(), new IAuthProvider[] {
            new CredentialsAuthProvider()
        }));
```

My `OnAuthenticated` method is very similar to the one in the SocialBoostrapApi demo; it walks through `session.ProviderOAuthAccess` and gets the necessary info out of them (looking for the OAuthTokens of the "ExternalProvider" provider).

Of course, this means that when the user gives authorization to my app on the external provider, in the OAuth callback I get the accesstoken, secret, everything, and I put it inside `session.ProviderOAuthAccess`.

This, of course, works fine for the current session, but if the user logs off and on again, it has to authorize again (get a new access token).

I need some way to save the data I put in session to a DB; I tried to look around but found nothing (see also [my question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17813438/863564)).

So, I added code to save them directly to the DB:

```
var userOAuthProvider = oauthTokens.TranslateTo<UserOAuthProvider>();
userOAuthProvider.UserAuthId = user.Id;
this.TryResolve<IDbConnectionFactory>().Run(db => db.Save(userOAuthProvider));
```

Now, when the user authenticates, it seems that ServiceStack gets all the tokens for this UserAuthId and put them inside session. Good!

### First question

Am I doing it in the correct way?

### Second question

Can I get rid of the `User`/`CustomUserSession` classes, and just store the additional info I need in the "Items" dictionary in `UserOAuthProvider`/`OAuthTokens`?
That would make my code simpler..

### Third question

At the end of `OnAuthenticate`, `SocialBootstrapApi` saves the custom User table again:

```
authService.TryResolve<IDbConnectionFactory>().Run(db => db.Save(user));
```

Why is it necessary? I suppose it is to copy back some info from the `UserOAuthProvider` table on the User table (at the next login after a new authorization, for example), but why? The session seems to be already initialized with the correct data.

Comment: This would be a better fit for [Code Review Stack Exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)