# Where's the best place to store UserId on UserAuth in ServiceStack

Tags: servicestack

We have got a service which uses Basic Authorization to validate a user's credentials.

It's all working well (checking against another database) but the issue is where to store the user's id. Setting UserAuth.Id doesn't work as the CredentialsAuthProvider appears to use this internally.

Using DisplayName feels wrong so where best should we store it to get it out of IAuthSession?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this earlier answer on [extending ServiceStack's authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11118747/85785). E.g. you can use the purpose-specific **RefId** to add a reference to an integer UserId or the string field **RefIdStr** for anything else.

Comment: Thanks I read that but I got the impression that it's persisting the details back into our datastore rather than Redis, is that not the case? Seems overkill to just store an int.

Comment: @Tim Right, the UserAuth is for DB (i.e. long-term persistence), but if you're setting it only once at Authentication it should matter. If you only want to store it on the Session, you can add as many custom fields you want to your own Custom Session.