# How does the ServiceStack Auth redirect works?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, servicestack, servicestack-auth

I'm trying to follow the Bootstrap ServiceStack code from http://bootstrapapi.apphb.com/

I can register a new user, but soon I do everything I want (create a new user on my table that extends the `UserAuth` table) in the `CreateUserAuth()` method from my `CustomUserAuth` **it redirects** to `http://localhost:50447/api/register`

I want to go back to the `Home` Controller...

What is the simple way to accomplish this?

In the docs, [under Authentication](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Authentication-and-authorization#custom-authentication-and-authorization), this is not very explicit, and I'm using the latest version to date: v4.0.30 and I'm implementing a custom `CredentialsAuthProvider`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `?Continue=/path` QueryString parameter to specify where it should redirect to.

If you're using your own custom UserAuth tables (i.e instead of [integrating with the existing UserAuth tables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11118747/85785)) you should subclass `OrmLiteAuthRepository<T,T>` class including your custom POCO's, e.g see the source for [OrmLiteAuthRepository](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Server/Auth/OrmLiteAuthRepository.cs#L12):

```
public class OrmLiteAuthRepository 
    : OrmLiteAuthRepository<UserAuth, UserAuthDetails>, IUserAuthRepository
{
    public OrmLiteAuthRepository(IDbConnectionFactory dbFactory) 
        : base(dbFactory) { }
}
```

Comment: I'm using NHibernate and ended up using the examples you have in the wiki regarding [`CustomUserAuthRepository`](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Authentication.NHibernate/NHibernateUserAuthRepository.cs) and a modified version of the [`CustomUserSession`](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/SocialBootstrapApi/blob/880d0893d5a99b39867d5961c9e5eb4ffdb5c64c/src/SocialBootstrapApi/Models/CustomUserSession.cs)