# Servicestack add field UserAuth table and check on login

Tags: authentication, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I want to add new field(s) on UserAuth table (for example : blocked, verified) and I want to check when login. How I can do this? I did not found any tutorial about customization authentication.

Comment: Refer to this previous answer for different ways of [extending ServiceStack Authentication and UserAuth models](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11118747/85785).

Comment: @mythz : Thank you, but its very confused. Finally I used cacheclient + session feauture with custom request filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found otherway solution for my project...

1) Add plug-in SessionFeaute :

```
this.Plugins.Add(new SessionFeature() { SessionExpiry = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15) });
```

2) Register ICacheClient :

```
  container.Register<ICacheClient>(new MemoryCacheClient());
```

3) Authenticate Method :

```
  public void Authenticate(ISession session , User user)
    {
        session.Set("UserInfo",user);
    }
```

4) Logout Method : `session.GetSessionBag().Set<User>("UserInfo",null);`

5) RequestFilter :

```
public class UserInfoFilterAttribute : RequestFilterAttribute
{
    public UserInfoFilterAttribute() { }
    public UserInfoFilterAttribute(ApplyTo applyTo) : base(applyTo) { }
    public override void Execute(IRequest req, IResponse res, object requestDto)
    {
            var user = req.GetSessionBag().Get<User>("UserInfo");
            if (user == null)
            {
              res.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
              res.EndRequest();
            }
    }
}
```

6) Finally Using Filter for restricted service.

```
  [UserInfoFilterAttribute]
public class AccountInfoService : ServiceStack.Service
{

}
```

Thanks anyway...