# ServiceStack customized user authentication primary id?

Tags: servicestack

i have customized my own implementation for ServiceStack's authentication. I created my own '`User`' table, which is inherited from `UserAuth`, so there is '`Id`' field from UserAuth, but now I created a '`UserId`' field (Guid) and set it to primary key in database, meanwhile i removed the '`Id`'. But ServiceStack throws an error when i tried to register a new user. If `UserId` and `Id` both exist, the `UserId` (which as been set as the primary key) doesn't get populated with Guid at all.

```
{
  "ResponseStatus": {
    "ErrorCode": "SqlException",
    "Message": "Invalid column name 'Id'.",
    "StackTrace": "[Register: 2/11/2015 5:12:41 AM]:\n[
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't change the primary key of the existing UserAuth table and use the built-in UserAuth repositories. You may need to create your own [Database AuthRepository](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Server/Auth/OrmLiteAuthRepository.cs) otherwise have a look at other ways to [extend ServiceStack User Auth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11118747/85785), if you want to use a Guid Primary Key then you'd need to create and reference an external table separate from UserAuth.