# What is the best way to create a new field for UserAuth?

Tags: authentication, servicestack

I would like to create a `DefaultPrinterId` property (field) attached on `UserAuth` table. This `DefaultPrinterId` field is a foreign key on a `Printer.Id` field (`Printer` is a custom table).

My question is, What is the best way to create a new field for UserAuth and fill property value after authentication?
Should I override `AuthUserSession`, `UserAuth`, `OrmLiteAuthRepository`?

I am a bit confused, even after reading documentation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd typically want to leave the `UserAuth` table fixed and instead use the [recommended approach for extending UserAuth is using the extension points available](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11118747/85785) but you are also able to extend the UserAuth tables for by inheriting your `CustomUserAuth` table from `UserAuth` and then instead of using `OrmLiteAuthRepository`, create a custom `MyOrmLiteAuthRepository` AuthProvider specifying the custom `UserAuth` and `UserAuthDetails` tables you want to use instead, e.g:

```
public class MyOrmLiteAuthRepository 
  : OrmLiteAuthRepository<CustomUserAuth, UserAuthDetails>
{
    public OrmLiteAuthRepository(IDbConnectionFactory dbFactory) : base(dbFactory) {}

    public OrmLiteAuthRepository(IDbConnectionFactory dbFactory, string namedConnection=null) 
      : base(dbFactory, namedConnection) {}
}
```