# ServiceStack: AuthUser vs IAuthSession - how do I retrieve the AuthUser?

Tags: servicestack, servicestack-auth

In previous Stack Overflow questions, @mythz tells about the Meta dictionary in the "UserAuth table".

However, I cannot find any information on where the UserAuth "table" is or where the object can be found. I am currently working with the `IAuthSession`, where I have some data regarding who is authenticated etc, but I cannot find info on where the UserAuth comes in.

I have read for example [How can I extend ServiceStack Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11117469/how-can-i-extend-servicestack-authentication/11118747#11118747) but that doesn't help - I see no reference to an "AuthUser" object.

So, how does the AuthUser relate to the IAuthSession?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [UserAuth](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/Auth/UserAuth.cs) classes are used by the [User Auth Repositories](http://docs.servicestack.net/authentication-and-authorization#user-auth-repository) to persist information on the User. If you're not using an Auth Repository the `UserAuth` and `UserAuthDetails` are not used.

E.g. For normal UserName/Password Credential Authentication, [Registering the User](http://docs.servicestack.net/authentication-and-authorization#built-in-auth-providers) (/register) will save their information in the `UserAuth` table. When they Authenticate (/auth/credentials) the registered `IAuthRepository` is used to validate their credentials against the `UserName` and `PasswordHash` stored in the `UserAuth` table, if successful the AuthProvider will populate the users [AuthUserSession](http://docs.servicestack.net/sessions#using-typed-sessions-in-servicestack) which is what's stored against the [Session Cookie Ids](http://docs.servicestack.net/sessions#cookie-session-ids) to enable the Authenticated UserSession.