# How to edit the DataTypes of properties in UserAuth

Tags: authentication, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I am new to ServiceStack, The extensiblity of this framework just blow my mind.
but it didnt seems to me any example to extend the data type of UserAuth. The IUserAuth interface seems to be tightly coupled with the framework.

Lets say i have a very large Database, and it is required to set UserAuth Id DataType as  **long** instead of **int**. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can’t change any of the existing IUserAuth schema properties but this answer covers different ways you can extend it
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11118747/85785

Comment: What will u recommend from your experience if **int** datatype will reach its limit i.e 2,147,483,647 rows in table ?

Comment: Over 2B+ users? Only Facebook/Google have systems with more than that many users. You can extract it in your own table in that case.